# Background-color in CSS conflicting with Google Adsense

Tags: adsense

I am using a background color to separate/highlight my comments within a book for a review site.  The book text is normal with no (white) background.  My comments use the following css:

```
#my-post-response{
  margin: 5px 5px 10px 20px;
  background-color:#FFFFCC;
  border: 3px solid #888;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  behavior: url(/border-radius.htc);
}
```

The problem is that the comments are in random areas and when google adsense is adjacent, the text doesn't overlap but the background-color does.  Please view this screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/qRexO78j2

Comment: FYI I see nothing at your Screencast link.

Comment: Can you post a link to the site itself, I need to take a look at the css properly to help you. But it looks like a clearing issue try adding the clear:both; or clear: left;/clear:right; and that should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles - Using clear: both; helped a lot!  Thank you.  Sorry for not posting a link to the site.  Not allowed to.  :/ 

Originally, I was hoping the background-color would adopt the same behavior as the text and get out of the way but still be adjacent to the element (Google adsense or image).  Is there a way to do this?  That would cut down on extra white space.  Thanks again.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult without being able to see the actual code. But it looks like a clearing issue try adding

`clear:both;` or `clear: left;`/`clear:right;` to the elements, that should get you going in the right direction.

As to the Background colour issue, try reordering the cleared elements so the element floating right appears first in the code and setting a z-index for both elements i.e. `z-index:100;` and `z-index: 200;`